# Raise exception if script fails

Tags: python, exception, automated-tests, control-flow

I have a python script, tutorial.py. I want to run this script from a file test_tutorial.py, which is within my python test suite. If tutorial.py executes without any exceptions, I want the test to pass; if any exceptions are raised during execution of tutorial.py, I want the test to fail.

Here is how I am writing test_tutorial.py, which does **not** produce the desired behavior:

```
from os import system
test_passes = False
try:
    system("python tutorial.py")
    test_passes = True
except:
    pass
assert test_passes
```

I find that the above control flow is incorrect: if tutorial.py raises an exception, then the assert line never executes.

What is the correct way to test if an external script raises an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no error `s` will be `0`:

```
from os import system
s=system("python tutorial.py")
assert  s == 0
```

Or use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

s = Popen(["python" ,"tutorial.py"],stderr=PIPE)

_,err = s.communicate() # err  will be empty string if the program runs ok
assert not err
```

Your try/except is catching nothing from the tutorial file, you can move everything outside the it and it will behave the same:

```
from os import system
test_passes = False

s = system("python tutorial.py")
test_passes = True

assert test_passes
```

Comment: Clever solution, though the line s=system("python tutorial.py") does not execute: it just raises an uncontrolled exception. So I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @aph, your try/except is redundant if you are trying to catch an exception from the other python file. It won't be raised by os.system, s=system("python tutorial.py") does also execute the code, I have tested it.

Comment: Nice solution, Padriac! I haven't used python to spawn subprocesses before, so this is instructive. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @aph,no worries. There are lots of different ways you could use subprocess this is just a simple example. If you just want to know if the program executed successfully then checking the return code or err as above would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import system
test_passes = False
try:
    system("python tutorial.py")
    test_passes = True
except:
    pass
finally:
    assert test_passes
```

This is going to solve your problem.

> `Finally` block is going to process if any error is raised. Check [**this**](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-341.html) for more information.It's usually using for file process if it's not `with open()` method, to see the file is safely closed.

Comment: nice idea, but this actually does not solve the problem. When I artificially introduce an error in tutorial.py and then run your suggested modification, the assert statement is never asserted. I think the problem is that the exception is somehow being registered as being external to the try statement. So when system("python tutorial.py") is executed, the error is not seen as part of the control flow.

Comment: `Finally` block will process there is an error or not, it's for important functions or processes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I executed the code written in the way you suggest and it does not behave in this way. The code never reaches the assert statement.