# including plots in an IPython Notebook without %matplotlib magic function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

### Setup:

I have an IPython Notebook I’d like to include in the tutorials section of my docs. I’ve written a .ipynb —> .rst conversion script (using pandoc) that works as follows: the notebook is first converted to a .py file, which is executed as a script, and if the script execution raises no exceptions, an .rst export is triggered and a link to that tutorial is built in the appropriate spot of the docs. That way, the tutorials can be integrated into my docs only under the condition that the code does what the tutorial says it does. This method was developed as a result of the following question: [Raise exception if script fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872223/raise-exception-if-script-fails)

Ok, so here is the problem. I’d like for some of the .ipynb tutorials to include in-line plots with matplotlib. The way I display plots in an IPython Notebook is using the magic function call:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

However, if this command appears in a python executable script, python raises an exception. So none of my tutorials can currently include plots.

### Question:

So my question is this: how can I include in-line plots in a Notebook in a way that will not raise an exception when the notebook is exported to a .py file and executed as a script? Or, short of that, any suggestions for another workaround?

Comment: It might be easier to strip the offending line before you run your program through normal python.

Comment: Why would you want the `inline` call to be included in the output docs? If your code is meant to be run in a normal  python script it makes sense that it fails.

Comment: @ari - I want the .rst file to show a pretty plot that can be read on my web-hosted docs. The only purpose of the script is to test that the rest of the code works, so that my docs remain up-to-date.

Comment: The .rst can include the png from the notebook? That's pretty neat! In that case as David said, stripping all the magics from the .ipnb before conversion, or from the .py before running it should do the trick.

Comment: Also, looking at the question you linked, you did not accept an answer. If one of those answers solved your problem, I would recommend accepting it--it can be a little disheartening to spend all that time answering a question and not getting the validation.

Comment: I think some people will not attempt to answer a question if they see the asker has too high a percentage of questions with no accepted answer, which is another good reason to accept answers.

Comment: Thanks for the gentle nudge, @ari, my poor percentage of selecting accepted answers was purely due to ignorance of SO protocol.

Comment: @DavidZwicker - I think this a fine workaround, and easy enough to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
if ipython:
    ipython.magic("matplotlib inline")
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there should be no real need to use `%matplotlib inline` magic in jupyter. Instead, this should display nicely:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot([3,4,2,5])
fig
```

Comment: This works even though `matplotlib.Figure` lacks the `._repr_html_()` method used by pandas tables and matplotlib animations, because the ipython formatter (which prettifies ordinary lists etc) has built in support for converting `Figure` instances to PNG etc.